# Problem with authentication error with password verify

Tags: php

I'm trying to implement passwordverify in the PDO syntax of php. I have my passwords hashed when registered. When I click on login this error pops up

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ';', expecting ',' or ')' in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\try\authenticate.php on line 25

This is my authenticate.php

```
<?php 
    require 'database-config.php';

    session_start();

    $username = "";
    $password = "";

    if(isset($_POST['username'])){
        $username = $_POST['username'];
    }
    if (isset($_POST['password'])) {
        $password = $_POST['password'];

    }

    echo $username ." : ".$password;

    $q = 'SELECT * FROM isalonusers WHERE username=:username AND password=:password';

    $query = $dbh->prepare($q);



    $query->execute(array(':username' => $username, ':password' => password_verify($_POST['password'], $password['password']));


    if($query->rowCount() == 0){
        header('Location: index.php?err=1');
    }else{

        $row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        session_regenerate_id();
        $_SESSION['sess_user_id'] = $row['id'];
        $_SESSION['sess_username'] = $row['username'];
        $_SESSION['sess_name'] = $row['name'];
        $_SESSION['sess_phone_number'] = $row['phone_number'];
        $_SESSION['sess_gender'] = $row['gender'];
        $_SESSION['sess_address'] = $row['address'];
        $_SESSION['sess_occupation'] = $row['occupation'];
        $_SESSION['sess_birth_date'] = $row['birth_date'];
        $_SESSION['sess_userrole'] = $row['user_type'];

        echo $_SESSION['sess_userrole'];
        session_write_close();

        if( $_SESSION['sess_userrole'] == "admin"){
            header('Location: adminhome.php');
        }else{
            header('Location: index.php?err=1');
        }


    }


?>
```

What is my syntax error for verifying my password?

Comment: Missing `)` on line 25.

Comment: This is the kind of thing a proper IDE would point out

Comment: Thanks sir Jon Stirling.The verification still didnt go through.now it goes to the error handler. My logic in the syntax is wrong and I don't know what to change :(

Comment: @shielamekelele Fetch the stored password based on the submitted user, _then_ verify against the submitted password.

Comment: This lacks enough debugging details (`var_dump` all the things) to tell what's going on. Read up on proper password_hash/verify usage, instead of using plain passowrds in the db (which is what this looks like).

Answer (score -1):

```
$query->execute(array(':username' => $username, ':password' => password_verify($_POST['password'], $password['password'])));
```

missing `)` in line 25

**update**

http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php

according to documentation `password_verify` will give boolean. all you have to do hash the user input password then compare with db password.
like below.

```
$query->execute(array(':username' => $username, ':password' => $user_input_hashed_password));
```

Comment: Thanks sir, I have already fixed this issue too. but the verification still doesn't go. I have something in my syntax wrong and I can't point it out. I have selected the table, my password there is hashed. My thoughts is to make a variable hashedPass then = passwordverify(the password inputted, the password in database). How can I do it sir?